# Determine the splitting type of a bundle with cokernel as $\mathcal{O}_2p$ or $\mathcal{O}_p\oplus\mathcal{O}_q$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, divisors-algebraic-geometry

In my situation, I want to determine the splitting type of a rank 2 vector bundle $\mathcal{F}$ fitted in an exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)\rightarrow\mathcal{F}|_{\mathbb{P^1}}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_{2p}\rightarrow 0,$$ and at the same time when $p\ne q$ are the points of degree 1 in $\mathbb{P^1}$,
$$0\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)\rightarrow\mathcal{G}|_{\mathbb{P^1}}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_{p}\oplus\mathcal{O}_{q}\rightarrow 0.$$

I think that the candidates of splitting type of each case are (2, -2), (1, -1), or (0, 0).

My question is that :

Q1. How to determine which is the type of bundle in each case?

Q2. If cannot in just this situation, what are the additional conditions to achieve?

Q3. Those cases are actually the different situation? Means that could I have $\mathcal{F}|_{\mathbb{P^1}}\ncong\mathcal{G}|_{\mathbb{P^1}}$?

Thank you for your interest.

Comment: It is more convenient to dualize your sequenes: $$0 \to F^\vee \to \mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(2) \to \mathcal{O}_{2p} \to 0$$ and $$0 \to G^\vee \to \mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(2) \to \mathcal{O}_p \oplus \mathcal{O}_q \to 0$$ and to analyze these.

Comment: @Sasha Thank you for your comment! But then how can I get the conclusion..? As I seen, I stucked the same problem for distinguish the first case from the second. Sorry for my dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the dual sequence twisted by $\mathcal{O}(-1)$:
$$
0 \to F^\vee(-1) \to \mathcal{O}(-1) \oplus \mathcal{O}(1) \to \mathcal{O}_{2p} \to 0.
$$
From the degree reasons it follows that $F^\vee(-1) \cong \mathcal{O}(-1-a) \oplus \mathcal{O}(-1+a)$ for some $a \ge 0$, and clearly
$$
a = \dim H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, F^\vee(-1)) = H^1(\mathbb{P}^1, F^\vee(-1)).
$$
On the other hand, from the exact sequence we see
\begin{align*}
H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, F^\vee(-1)) 
&= \mathrm{Ker}(
H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(-1) \oplus \mathcal{O}(1)) \to 
H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}_{2p})
) \\
&= \mathrm{Ker}(
H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(1)) \to 
H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}_{2p})
).
\end{align*}
Now, there are three options for the morphism $\mathcal{O}(1) \to \mathcal{O}_{2p}$:

- an epimorphism with kernel $\mathcal{O}(-1)$;
- a composition $\mathcal{O}(1) \to \mathcal{O}_{p} \to \mathcal{O}_{2p}$ with kernel $\mathcal{O}$;
- the zero map with kernel $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

These correspond to cases $a = 0$, $a = 1$, and $a = 2$, respectively.

A similar analysis applies to the case of vector bundle $G$ and gives exactly the same three possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! It is so helpful for me. Then, we cannot distinguish the case $\mathcal{F}$ from $\mathcal{G}$ just in case, isn't it? I think so I need more information for the surjective map in the sequences to decision the splitting type for each case.

Comment: The possible types are indeed the same in the two cases.